# How to convert mega menu into Hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a mega menu what needs to be adapted to view on mobile devices. I am struggling including submenu and adjusting layout in Hamburger menu.
I am aiming for something like this  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji54k.png but I am not able to find how to adjust that in hamburger menu

I have this code
https://jsfiddle.net/07jokthn/2/

```
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.menu');
const navLinks=document.querySelectorAll('.menu li');


burger.addEventListener('click', () =>{
     //Toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
       // Animate Links 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added two menus - one normal horizontal mega menu and another burger. I have set one to appear while another stays hidden. It does the thing I need it to be doing. I am not sure if this correct way, but I am happy to close the question.